# HTML5 mobile keyboard covers the input in Full screen mode

Tags: javascript, android, css, html

Working on a mobile html5 app, on Android using chrome browser behaviour is good but once added to homescreen and used in full screen mode I run into the following **problem**:

When pressing the text input positioned in the footer the **page does not move up - the keyboard covers it so you can't see what you are typing**.

I need it to push the page normaly up just as when it is viewed in browser mode

This is what I have **in the header**:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

and the **bottom footer**:

```
<div class="footer pos-fixed">
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="ajax-message" method="post" action="blabla">

                    <input name="conversation_id" value="1" type="hidden">
                    <input name="receipient_id" value="14" type="hidden">

                <div class="marg-10">
                        <textarea style="" class="text-input-box" name="message" rows="1"></textarea>

                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Send</button>
                </div>


                <input name="_token" value="xx" type="hidden">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

ps: I am also using **latest bootsrap & jquery**

Comment: Sadly, even innerHeight/outerHeight/screen.height doesn't change when opening keyboard on fullscreen.

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but for anyone needing a solution -- here's my personal approach ...

### HTML

```
<form>
  <input type="email" id="inputEmail">
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword">
</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
var deviceIsAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (deviceIsAndroid) {
        $(document).bind("click", function () {
            if (document.activeElement.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA' || document.activeElement.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
                var textBox = document.activeElement.id;
                document.getElementById(textBox).scrollIntoView();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The first part makes it *Android* specific (in the event that the application/site is accessible on other devices).
Any click will trigger the function, but nothing will happen unless it occurs in a `textArea` or `input` field.
This can be simplified even further if you're only working with a single, field type ...

```
$("input").bind("click", function () {
    var textBox = document.activeElement.id;
    document.getElementById(textBox).scrollIntoView();
});
```

Comment: is this only work for android?